# Swagger Inspector version of C# call failing when using token

Tags: rest, token, swagger

I have the following code:

```
string tokenValue = "221e0a91-6530-4790-a969-d1da75b0afd2";
// Configure httpClient to use the above token.
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("token", tokenValue);
```

The subsequent calls (HEAD, POST, GET) all work fine.

When I try to do the same thing using Swagger Inspector, it fails.  I am able to get a token using Swagger Inspector site, and I place the token into a HEAD call as follows:

[image]

But as I said, the call fails, with "Authorization has been denied for this request." message returned as an XML file.

I also tried the two other options available on the same page: Basic Authentication, and OAuth 2.0/JWT, all with HTTPS.  They all fail.

How can I go about understanding why it's failing?

Also: Is what I am using above called "Bearer Authentication"?

Comment: Does your request URL [support CORS](https://enable-cors.org/)?

Comment: @Helen I really don't know.  I have access to the server that hosts the endpoint.  Is there something I can do to find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have below 2 things to mention from your screenshot:

1. Response for `HEAD` method never contains the response body, it always contains the response headers
   for more details of `HEAD`: [`HEAD Request`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.2)

   But in your case response-body is also present (maybe of CML content type).
2. You should use OAuth 2.0/JWT option on the same page to pass the token along with your request.

To answer your question related to *Bearer Authentication*:
No, the one you are trying to use is not at all Bearer Authentication.
In your case, "token" will be considered as Custom/User HTTP Header.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) But did it resolve your issue. If not then please let me know what kind of error/problem you are getting now.

Comment: I can't test it at this moment, but your description is helpful nevertheless, especially the first point.